# How do you change the all uppercase Django Admin inline names to proper title case?

Tags: django, django-admin

In the Django Admin portal if you collapse fieldsets the name and the show link are in proper/title case, but when you collapse inline they are in all uppercase.  See screenshots below where the 'Date Information (Show)' is not in all uppercase, but the 'CHOICES (SHOW)' is.  I would just like them to both look the same and not sure how to accomplish that.  I already tried using a class of 'lowercase', but that didn't change the inline format.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inline title style is set by a css class named `inline-group h2`. So if you need to override this class, you need to define your custom css.

1. Add a custom stylesheet to your static root `custom.css`

#### custom.css

```
.no-upper h2 {
  text-transform: unset;
}
```

2. [Define css media in your model admin class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions), and add `no-upper` class to your inline field

#### admin.py

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):                                           
    ...                                                                   
    classes = ('collapse', 'no-upper')                                             


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                                             
    ...                                              
    class Media:                                                                   
        css = {                                                                    
            'all': ('css/custom.css', )                                            
        }
```

Comment: yes, that worked following your steps and adding the STATICFILES_DIRS to settings.py, so thanks!